# PHP Symfony 1.4 - best way to pass data from action to a component?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I making breadcrumbs menu in my symfony application: I create a list of links in execute{Action}, then I use a component in layout.php to display it, so I'm looking for way to pass data from action to this component. I can use sfContext as registry, but maybe there's a better way?

Comment: Seems like using flash variables is commonly seen in the docs to do this. I agree that this is hackery, and it's one of the biggest black eyes of 1.4 that I often run into, in the form of forwarding from one action to another.

Answer (score 3):

Typically you would use a slot so in the action's view:

`slot('breadcrumb', $links);`

And then in your layout.php:

```
<?php if(has_slot('breadcrumb')): ?>
  <?php include_component('modulename', 'breadcrumb', get_slot('breadcrumb')); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Essentially `slot` uses a special namespace in the context (or maybe its the response... some instance of sfParameterHolder somewhere, hehe) as a registry for slot names/values - so the solution you were thinking of is already implemented :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my problem is that breadcrumbs component has to be included anyway, even if links were not defined in action - then it (component) generates links. And I wouldn't want to pass breadcrumbs links to action's template, because I think it's even less elegant than using registry.

Comment: Well another solution is to move breadcrumb generation (determiniation and assembling of links) from the component to a separate class. Then you can inject this class into the context on `context.load_factories` initializing it with the current `sfWebRequest` which i would think would be enough to work out your bread crumb. If its not you could also hook this same class into the `controller.change_action` event to push resolved actions into it. Kind of hard to say without knowing how your breadcrumb is compiled. Then you would just fetch this breadcrumb class from the component.

Answer (score 2):

In your action:

```
$this->links = array('link1', 'link2', 'linkn');
```

In your template:

```
<?php include_component('modulename', 'breadcrumb', array('links' => $links); ?>
```